# Possessed Cinema that kills its teenage customers in various ways

Tags: story-identification, novel, horror

I remember reading a book in the mid to late 1990's that had a possessed Cinema that killed its customers in a number of different ways.

One girl dropped something on the floor, and when she bent down her hair got stuck in some chewing gum under the seat, and she was then pulled into it.

A male and female were killed in the middle of a sex act. The male was seen as a geeky or dumb teenager, but was known by several female teenagers as being well endowed.

Two police officers crashed their car into the front of the cinema, and were surrounded by the light at the front of the cinema. They find out if they enter the darkness surrounding them they will die, so they spend all night on the bonnet of the car.

A teenage was eaten/attacked by a cockroach/bug within the toilet cubicles, or they were drowned as the toilets overflow.

Most if not all of the teenagers watching the movie were killed in some way, there are a number of slightly sexual references in the book (death during the sex act as well as references to the girl being eaten by the chewing gum), but the book isn't explicitly erotica and is more thriller/horror.

The book ends with the day becoming normal and the possession ending, I think only the police officers survived.

Comment: Was the cover mostly yellowish, with a movie theater entrance?  I had such a book and read it ages ago but don't know if it is or isn't the one you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

*The Late Show* by John Douglas could be a possibility.

Description and blurb from [amazon.co.uk](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Late-Show-John-Douglas/dp/0340632348):

> A horror novel which takes place at a run-down cinema in a Northern
> town, when a weekend all-night screening of horror movie classics
> turns into a literal slaughter as the malevolent spirit of the place
> has awoken to exact a dreadful tale of sacrifice, and the cinema
> itself has become an instrument of death.

> IT'S AN ALL-NIGHT MOVIE HORRORSHOW - BUT THIS TIME IT'S FOR REAL ...
>
> It seemed like a good idea at the time: get the run-down old cinema
> packed for once by putting on an all-night screening of splatter
> movies. Bring the teenage punters in by the carload.
>
> But what the organizers hadn't reckoned on was the embittered owner of
> the Plaza entering into a nightmare pact with the evil entity that
> haunted the site - and that, after decades of enforced abstinence, it
> would be ravenous for 'real' gore.
>
> Which was how the carnage on the screen became nothing compared to the
> real-life bloodletting in the stalls, circle and corridors of the
> Plaza. The audience screamed and screamed again - but there was no
> exit ...
>
> GETTING IN IS CHEAP. GETTING OUT COULD COST YOU YOUR LIFE.

Comment: This might be it, the name rings a bell. It dosent seem to exist in a kindle/epub version so I might have to have a look on eBay to see if there is a cheap version I can purchase to check